# Tool to put text on desktop wallpaper

Tags: windows, desktop, desktop-customization

I'd like to put a list of keyboard shortcuts I want to learn on my desktop wallpaper so I can show and hide it quickly by pressing Win+D.

I'll want to be changing the list quite frequently as I remove ones that I've learnt and add new ones, so I don't want something that takes too long to make changes.

What tools are there to do this?

---

Followup: For the original use-case, shortcuts I now use a `data:text/html,<html>...` bookmark that chrome will sync between my home and work computers. However I've taken to creating "Motivational Posters" on my desktop background and **I would still like a solution other than BgInfo as I find it's font rendering jaggy/pixelated** . (If I do get BgInfo to render better I could make the "posters" change randomly by [Scripting BGInfo For Random Wallpaper](http://www.cj-gerow.com/ceg/?p=1061)).

For those interested in the keyboard shortcut bookmarks here is an example. Put this in a bookmark:

```
data:text/html,<title>Keyboard Shortcuts</title><style>kbd {border: 1px solid lightgrey; padding: 2px;background-color: #FDF4DC; }</style><h1>Keyboard Shortcuts</h1><dl><dt>Copy</dt><dd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd></dd><dt>Paste</dt><dd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd></dd><dt>Cut</dt><dd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd><dt>Erase input</dt><dd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd></dd><dt>Tab Word</dt><dd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>&larr;</kbd>/<kbd>&rarr;</kbd></dd><pre>commands list:%0ACMD1%0ACMD2</pre>
```

Comment: I want one for mac, thinking of asking this question yesterday. Fancy adding mac os x to the tags and question? :p

Comment: @danixd: try GeekTool http://lifehacker.com/software/top/download-of-the-day--geektool-185802.php

Comment: @nhinkle It's not "hardware shopping recommendations". What's the problem?

Comment: Somone chose the wrong close reason. It should have been "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic...". The new site http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is now a better fit ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A very useful and simple to use tool is BgInfo: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557.aspx

You can either edit the text area directly through BgInfo, or you can have it read the contents from a locally stored text file.

Note: if you use the text file option, you'll need some sort of scheduled task to automate picking up any changes to the document

Comment: Makes a mess of the wallpapers on 7 & 8

Comment: The thing that bugs me about BgInfo is that the fonts aren't rendered with antialiasing/cleartype and I can see a lot of pixels on curved letters.

Comment: @SamHasler I totally agree. BGInfo seems to have hit a wall as far as development goes. Since there have been no updates for a while (and no indication of any upcoming in the forum) I wouldn't expect any change to this issue. Sadly I don't use anything like this any more so I don't know of a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for http://rainmeter.net/RainCMS/ -- it lets you display text files on your desktop.

Comment: seems a bit overkill. Does it stay up when minimising windows with Win+D though?

Answer (score 0):

I have used a BAT script with grep for windows (separate download) to generate a text file that "whoami" would display and gotten the information that I needed to display.

http://www.kewlit.com/whoami/

I don't remember which version I used but BgInfo may be a better solution if it allows scripting or including text files.